# Android notification gets cleared on opening App via app launcher

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have created a new application in which for showing notification used NotificationCompat Notify method. Defining a functionality that notification should get dismissed only on clicking it or swiping it.
It should not get dismissed on opening app via launcher (same like telegram app)

Tried so far,
setAutocancel method to dismiss the notification on clicking or swiping.
but I couldn't able to stop the dismiss when app gets opened via launcher

Also, I have tried showing notification using foreground service but it is not supporting swipe dismiss behaviour.

Is there anyway to support swipe dismiss and notification shouldn't get dismissed when I open app via app launcher

Comment: can someone help me on this, I got struck at this point